# Thymeleaf fragment processor and Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Could somebody, please, help with Thymeleaf? I need to create a template layout and I've got stuck with `<div th:fragment="content"></div>`. The point is `layout:fragment` doesn't replace code on the dashboard page. By the way, other processors like `layout:decorate` or `th:replace` works well. I'm using Intellij IDEA with Spring 2.5.4.

[My template structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCo6R.png)

#dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{admin/share/template.html}">
    <head>
        <title>Admin dashboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content">
            <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <style th:replace="~{admin/share/style}"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app-container app-theme-white body-tabs-shadow fixed-sidebar fixed-header">
    <div th:replace="/admin/share/header"></div>
    <div class="app-main">
        <div th:replace="/admin/share/sidebar"></div>
        <div class="app-main__outer">
            <div class="app-main__inner">
                <div th:fragment="content">
                    <p>Page content goes here</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:replace="/admin/share/js"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#Thymeleaf.class

```
@Configuration
public class Thymeleaf {
    @Bean
    public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
        return new LayoutDialect();
    }
}
```

[Result of Dashboard page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfJ4q.png)

UPDATE:

The issue is solved. Just need to use `layout:fragment` instead of `th:fragment` =)

Comment: Have you tried adding the dialect like this? `TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
`
As stated in: https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/getting-started/

Comment: Is it possible that on `#dashboard.html` you meant `layout:decorate="~{/admin/share/template.html}"` instead of `layout:decorate="~{admin/share/template.html}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use `layout:fragment` instead of `th:fragment` =)